# How can I use a for loop to import multiple data files in Neo4j?

Tags: for-loop, neo4j

Suppose I have a list of paths to five CSV files that I would like to import, that all have the same structure. How can I simply do something like this?

```
for path in paths:
       LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM path as row
       WITH row
       CREATE (n:Person { name : name})
       ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible with Cypher. Use some preprocessing tool either aggregate your csv files into one or call `LOAD CSV` for each of the files.

For preprocessing [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org) is a good choice.